# Confused by results of a simple computation

Tags: functions, precision-and-accuracy

If I define

```
f[x_] := (1 - Exp[-2 x^2])/(x Sin[x])
```

and then enter

```
N[f[10^-5] - 2, 100]
```

I get the result
$$-1.6666666665627777777825701058199280191798996849964591555949605677854\
31348232514315228566944038032233 \times 10^{-10}$$
This is more or less what I expect, because $f(x) \approx 2 - (5/3)x^2$ for small $x$.  However, if I enter

```
N[f[0.00001] - 2, 100]
```

I get the result $1.65514 \times 10^{-7}$.

There is a big difference, relatively speaking, between $-1.6 \times 10^{-10}$ and $+1.6 \times 10^{-7}$. What's going on?  I am using Mathematica 12.2.

Comment: @CarlWoll I confess that I did not completely see the relevance of the answer to the linked-to question, but the answer by Daniel Huber is sufficiently exhaustive that even I can understand it.  The part I was missing was the distinction between 10^-5 and 0.00001 and their handling by Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of f[10^-5] is an exact number. On the contrary, the result of f[0.00001] is obtained using machine precision arithmetic. If you then say: N[f[0.00001] - 2, 100], The evaluation loop of MMA first evaluates the arguments of N, that is f[0.00001] and this uses machine precision. Afterwards N can not give you more accurate results than its input and that is machine precision.

Consider e.g.:

```
N[f[10^-5] - 2, 100]
```

[image]

Here you get 100 valid digits. On the other hand:

```
N[f[0.00001] - 2, 100] // FullForm
```

[image]

Here you get 16 digits what corresponds to machine precision, but these need not be all valid as shown below.

First point: N can not increase precision!!!

Further, f[0.00001] is a number close to 2 with 16 digits precision. In addition to the smaller precision, it also carries errors due to machine precision calculations. You can easily seen this by comparing:

N[f[10^-5], 20]

f[0.00001] // FullForm

[image]

The latter is a result with only 7 digits precision. If you now subtract 2 You end up with  0 digits of precision! Because during calculations in machine precision the precision is not tracked, the output of machine calculations will always show 16 digits precision but you have no guarantee that all digits are valid.

Point two: Precision of machine calculations is not tracked and is always 16, but the number of valid digits may be  much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want with

```
f[x_] := (1 - Exp[-2 x^2])/(x Sin[x])

N[f[0.00001`110] - 2, 100]

-1.666666666562777777782570105819928019179899684996459155594960567785431348232514315228566944038032233*10^-10
```

I added the extra 10 digits of precision to `0.00001` to allow for some round off error in the final result.